# Unable to ping to outside network from behind a Linux router

Tags: iptables

My system is behind a Linux firewall, where eth0 is connected to internet and eth1 is connected to my LAN. The issue is I am not able to ping to outside my network. 
The iptables rule I have used here as below.

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p icmp  -j SNAT  --to-source $PUBLICIP

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong here.

Packet forwarding is enabled by the kernel.

The script containing iptables rules are as follows.

```
IPT=/sbin/iptables

echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_ecn
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/proxy_arp
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward


# Removing Ipchains modules and inserting IPT modules
/sbin/rmmod ipchains &> /dev/null
/sbin/modprobe ip_tables
/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_ftp
/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_irc


# Connection tracking module
/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack &> /dev/null
/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp &> /dev/null
/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_irc


# Flush Default Rules
/sbin/iptables -F
/sbin/iptables -t nat -F
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -F
/sbin/iptables -F INPUT
/sbin/iptables -F FORWARD
/sbin/iptables -F OUTPUT
/sbin/iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
/sbin/iptables -t nat -F PREROUTING
/sbin/iptables -t nat -F OUTPUT
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -F PREROUTING
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -F OUTPUT

# Setting Default policies on rules
/sbin/iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -P INPUT DROP
/sbin/iptables -P FORWARD DROP

/sbin/iptables -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t nat -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

LANIF="lo eth1 ppp0"

for x in ${LANIF}
do
$IPT -A INPUT -i ${x} -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD  -i ${x} -j ACCEPT
done



#Google DNS
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 8.8.8.8 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source $PUBLICIP
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 8.8.4.4 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source $PUBLICIP


/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.76  -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source $PUBLICIP    
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.3  -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source $PUBLICIP     
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.68  -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source $PUBLICIP    



/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED \
-j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED \
-j ACCEPT

# List The Rules
echo "###########  FILTER  ############################"
/sbin/iptables -L -n -v
echo ""
echo "###########    NAT   ############################"
/sbin/iptables -t nat -L -n -v
echo ""
echo "###########  MANGLE  ############################"
/sbin/iptables -t mangle -L -n -v
echo ""
echo "#################################################"
```

Comment: Ok, you NATed the icmp, but did you actually put in any rules in the FORWARD chan that allow it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled packet forwarding by the kernel?

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Can you also paste your full iptables rules?

Comment: Hi 
Yes packet forwarding is enabled by the kernel.
I have pasted my full iptables rules in my next post.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're forgetting to NAT the FORWARD traffic. Try adding the following rule:

```
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT -to-source $PUBLICIP
```

This will make sure that all traffic going out `eth0` will not leak internal IP addresses and should solve your problem.

Best of luck,
João Miguel Neves